# Why it is showing error for DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentplatform?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

Why it is showing error for DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentplatform?

I'm trying to connect flutter app to firebase and I implemented dependencies correctly,but showing error on DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentolatform.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I imagine it was just that the symbol can't be found.  I just ran into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue after checking in the repository of Firebase. found that that has created a separated class for that you can take reference from here.
Hope it will work.

````
// Copyright 2022, the Chromium project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

// File generated by FlutterFire CLI.
// ignore_for_file: lines_longer_than_80_chars, avoid_classes_with_only_static_members
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' show FirebaseOptions;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'
    show defaultTargetPlatform, kIsWeb, TargetPlatform;

/// Default [FirebaseOptions] for use with your Firebase apps.
///
/// Example:
/// ```dart
/// import 'firebase_options.dart';
/// // ...
/// await Firebase.initializeApp(
///   options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
/// );
/// ```
class DefaultFirebaseOptions {
  static FirebaseOptions get currentPlatform {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return web;
    }
    switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
      case TargetPlatform.android:
        return android;
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
        return ios;
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
        return macos;
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for windows - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for linux - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      default:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions are not supported for this platform.',
        );
    }
  }
````

[Reference github link](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics/example/lib/firebase_options.dart)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem.  It happens if you use a tool (like following the [Firebase setup instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web)) that will automatically create `firebase_options.dart` for you.  The tool creates it in `{project_root}/lib/` right next to main.dart, but if you try to initialize Firebase in a different library like I did, it can't find `DefaultFirebaseOptions`.

I had added the dependency for firebase_core in the library, but what I didn't realize was that `DefaultFirebaseOptions` is actually defined in the `firebase_options.dart` file that is created and updated for you by the `flutterfire configure` command.  It's a class with properties unique to your Firebase app.

[image: File Tree showing generated firebase_options.dart location]

So, you can either add a dependency on the root project library to the .yaml for the sub project.

OR

Just initialize Firebase in the main.dart file like the documention mentions (but I initially took as only a suggestion).

```dart
import 'package:yourproject/firebase_options.dart'; // <-- Need this import
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp(const MainAppWidget());
}
```